# Enable Text Selection Behind jQuery Mobile Dialog/Popup/Panel

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile slide panel from which a user can choose some eReader-type options (highlight, search, define, etc.). Problem is when the slide panel is open and active, the user is unable to select text from the page.

The result is that to use the features, a user has to select the text they wish to highlight, THEN open the slide panel to highlight it. Obviously not a very good UX.

I have searched through SO and jQuery Mobile documentation and haven't found a way to enable user selection while a dialog, popup, or panel is active. Does anyone here have any thoughts on the subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved you only need to change some CSS.

### First part

jQuery Mobile popup and panel have a hidden overlay div that covers full screen height and width while popup and panel are open.

You will need to do only one thing. Use some browser tool for HTML structure viewing and check the name of overlay div, then just set it this css property:

```
display: none;
```

in case it has only class name you will need to do it like this:

```
display: none !important;
```

If you wish I can even create you a working example.

### Second part

Now this part is tricky and it works for popup. jQuery Mobile js code prevent background text selection through javascript.

It can be fix manually through, basically you will need to modify jQuery Mobile javascript file, uncompressed one. And compress it again after you made all changes.

Open jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 js file (uncompressed version), go to line 8505, it looks like this:

```
if ( tgt !== ui.container[ 0 ] ) {
    $tgt = $( e.target );
    if ( 0 === $tgt.parents().filter( ui.container[ 0 ] ).length ) {
        $( document.activeElement ).one( "focus", function( e ) {
            $tgt.blur();
        });
        ui.focusElement.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    } else if ( ui.focusElement[ 0 ] === ui.container[ 0 ] ) {
        ui.focusElement = $tgt;
    }
}
```

Change it to this:

```
if ( tgt !== ui.container[ 0 ] ) {
    /*$tgt = $( e.target );
    if ( 0 === $tgt.parents().filter( ui.container[ 0 ] ).length ) {
        $( document.activeElement ).one( "focus", function( e ) {
            $tgt.blur();
        });
        ui.focusElement.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
    } else if ( ui.focusElement[ 0 ] === ui.container[ 0 ] ) {
        ui.focusElement = $tgt;
    }*/
}
```

Background selection will now work. If you are using older jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 or 1.3 just find same function and do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, Gajotres. That's sort of what I expected, however, I'm struggling to identify the overlay div. What browser tool would you suggest to view the HTML structure? I thought I could track it down quickly using Dreamweaver, but it isn't showing me what I need to see.

Comment: Give me few minutes and I will create you a working example. Just tell me what jQuery Mobile version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.3.0. I found some documentation that refers to the "invisible layers" when using jQM panels. It basically says exactly what you've described here, but doesn't identify the layer name unfortunately.

Comment: Here's a simple tutorial for Chrome: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNsM2PUkZ1g, just open it and press CTRL+SHIFT+I. Same thing goes for Firefox but final implementation is little bit different.

Comment: Progress! The overlay layer is referred to as a "screen" and thus the ID in question is simply the unique ID of the popup that I've defined with "-screen" appended. Now, however, although I now see the text-selection cursor (rather than the arrow I saw before), I am still unable to select any text with the popup panel open. One mystery solved, another opened.

Comment: I have a second pat of solution for you but you may not like it. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: That did the trick! I can't tell you how happy this makes me. Thank you so much for your help. Would vote this up a million times!

Comment: I am glad to help m8 :)